# kivy error: OSError: File data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttfs not found and also im on windows 8.1

Tags: python, kivy

"main.py"

```
from kivy.app import App
     class WeatherApp(App):
         pass
     if __name__="__main__":
         WeatherApp().run()
```

"weather.kv"

```
Label:
   text: "hello world"
```

i am expecting a window with a black background and the words "hello world"
in the middle

Comment: Can you please format your code properly?

Comment: Also, can you specify: 1) what are you trying to do, 2) error details and what 3) what is the result you're expecting

Comment: question summary edited

Answer (score 1):

For me I managed to solve

1. Editing the spec file like so:

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
    from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
    block_cipher = None
    
    
    a = Analysis(['hello.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\<username>\\PycharmProjects\\<project_dir>'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              [],
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='hello',
              debug=False,
              bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
                   Tree('C:\\Users\\<username>\\PycharmProjects\\<project_dir>'),
                   a.binaries,
                   a.zipfiles,
                   a.datas,
                   *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
                   strip=False,
                   upx=True,
                   upx_exclude=[],
                   name='hello')
```

2. by copying the kivymd dir ***C:\Users<username>\Anaconda3\envs<project_name>\Lib\site-packages\kivymd*** to your ***dist*** folder

Answer (score 0):

## Roboto-Regular.ttfs Not Found - Windows 8.1

Currently, in the Kivy config file, the default fonts used for widgets displaying any text defaults to [‘Roboto’, ‘data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf’, ‘data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf’, ‘data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf’, ‘data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf’].
The latest version of Roboto can be found at https://github.com/google/roboto/releases

There is a typo error and indentation problem in your app. After fixing the problems, your app should works as shown in the example below.

Replace:

```
if __name__="__main__":
```

with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    WeatherApp().run()
```

### weather.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

Label:
   text: "hello world"
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - Hello World]

Comment: The typo was only in the above version not in my actual code XD. THE error still exists

Comment: And also I ran it on Linux it worked, but not in Windows 8.1

Comment: I have updated my post. The latest version of Roboto can be found at https://github.com/google/roboto/releases